# How do I concat two columns to make a new column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data.

```
     datetime user_id song_id
1  2019-03-26       6      31
2  2019-03-26       4      30
3  2019-03-26       3      31
4  2019-03-26       9      34
5  2019-03-26      10      21
6  2019-03-26       8      38
7  2019-03-26       8      33
8  2019-03-26       8      28
9  2019-03-26       6      30
```

I'd like to make a third column, so the data looks like this

```
     datetime user_id song_id    usersong_id
1  2019-03-26       6      31    631
2  2019-03-26       4      30    430
3  2019-03-26       3      31    331
4  2019-03-26       9      34    934
5  2019-03-26      10      21    1021
6  2019-03-26       8      38    838
7  2019-03-26       8      33    833
8  2019-03-26       8      28    828
9  2019-03-26       6      30    630
```

I tried this code.

```
df %>%
  group_by(user_id, song_id) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(usersong_id = c(user_id, song_id))
```

But, it gave me this error:

> Error: Column `usersong_id` must be length 1 (the group size), not 2

Comment: can you not do `df$usersong_id <- paste0(df$user_id, df$song_id)`?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     unite(user_song_id, user_id, song_id, sep = "", remove = FALSE) %>%
     select(names(df), user_song_id)
#    datetime user_id song_id user_song_id
#1 2019-03-26       6      31          631
#2 2019-03-26       4      30          430
#3 2019-03-26       3      31          331
#4 2019-03-26       9      34          934
#5 2019-03-26      10      21         1021
#6 2019-03-26       8      38          838
#7 2019-03-26       8      33          833
#8 2019-03-26       8      28          828
#9 2019-03-26       6      30          630
```

Comment: Off topic - do you know if there is any way to use `left_join` without getting `.x` and `.y` added to columns of the same name? especially when they have the same values.

Comment: .x and .y will get added if the column names clash

Comment: @Cauder Not clear about the situation.  If you don't want to have extra columns, subset one of the dataset columns without the intersecting columns before the left_join

Comment: Yeah, but what about cases where the column names are the same and the values are the same? I still get `.x` and `.y` added. No biggie, just curious.

Comment: Aha, that's really a great idea

Answer (score 2):

You could use any of the below:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(usersong_id = paste0(user_id, song_id))

df <- df %>%
  unite(user_song_id, user_id, song_id, sep = "", remove = FALSE)

df$usersong_id <- paste0(df$user_id, df$song_id)
```

Comment: @akrun Oh didn't notice. You are too fast :-)